# How to use two different AWS S3 accounts with CarrierWave?

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, minio

I use CarrierWave to handle my Rails6 application images and assets on AWS S3. I want to migrate the assets part to Minio (so, still `carrierwave-aws` but, with a different configuration) while keeping the other image on S3.

Can I achieve such a goal with CarrierWave?

Thank you.